# How to use Intel SGX service provider certificate with Ubuntu and Android?

Tags: android, https, certificate, intel, sgx

I have already posted this question in the Intel Forums, but my schedule is limited and I need a quick answer, so I am reaching out to all available media.

I am developing a small Intel SGX Application that does remote attestation with an Android Service Provider. I need your help trying to understand how to use the certificate that I have registered with Intel to make HTTPS requests to the IAS (as referenced in the [documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/7e/3b/ias-api-spec.pdf)).

I have a small test Java program that makes a simple Retreive SigRL GET request to the IAS, just to test out if it works at all. But I keep getting SSLHandshakeException when it tries to execute the HTTPS request.

Java Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

public class Prog {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        makeRequest();
    }

    public static void makeRequest() throws Exception {

        String url = "https://test-as.sgx.trustedservices.intel.com:443/attestation/sgx/v2/sigrl/00000010";
        URL target = new URL(url);

        /* Force TLSv1.2 */
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sc.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());

        /* Set up HTTP properties. */
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) target.openConnection();
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        /* Obtain and check response status quote. */
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        /* Read response body into a String */
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer responseBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
            responseBuffer.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        String response = responseBuffer.toString();

        /* Evaluate result and print messages. */
        System.out.println("HTTP response status code: " + responseCode + "\n");
        System.out.println(response);
    }

}
```

Console output:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2038)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1135)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at Prog.makeRequest(Prog.java:32)
    at Prog.main(Prog.java:13)
```

[This tutorial](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-create-self-signed-certificates-for-use-with-intel-sgx-remote-attestation-using) generates a client.pfx file that can be used to import the certificate to other platforms. I have copied this file to the Ubuntu system that runs my Java program and double-clicked it to import it. Everything seemed sucessful, but I still keep getting these Exceptions when running the program.

I have also installed the client.crt file on Android using the option in (Settings)>(Lockscreen and security)>(Other security settings)>(Credential Storage/Install from device storage). When I try to run this code from an Android Activity (just by copypasting the method), I get the exact same error.

I need to be able to make the IAS requests both from Ubuntu and Android (7.0, API 24). The certificate I generated using this tutorial is already registered with Intel (I have received E-Mail confirmation and a service provider ID from Intel Developer Services).

In principle the only thing I need to know is how to properly use/install the certificate that I generated on both Ubuntu and on Android and if I am properly issuing the HTTP request in the program. I am still a student and I need to work with SGX for a project, so please bear with my limited knowledge. I would be very grateful for an answer.